# How to force overwrite changes on a specific file every git pull?

Tags: git, github, cicd, git-pull

On GitHub I have an action that creates, automatically at every commit, a file with the latest news.

It happens that the editor to visualize the file can change it with some metadata, formatting tabs and so on.

This cause that frequently when I pull code, I have this error:

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 23 (delta 12), reused 23 (delta 12), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (23/23), 3.87 KiB | 3.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:<org>/<repo>
   7584f6c..9c9eefa  main       -> origin/main
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        news.md
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 10873f9..9c9eefa
```

and I need to stash first:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

but this is very annoying because it may happen frequently (every time I need to pull).

I cannot find a solution that help me on that. Is it possible to overwrite changes during the pull automaticaly for the specific file?

Comment: you can set an alias/a script for that sequence, or for `git checkout HEAD -- news.md && git pull "$@"`

Comment: [`git pull --autostash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---autostash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments, as solution, I used a two-ways workaround.

If I need to pull programmatically I use an alias inside a script:

```
git checkout HEAD -- news.md && git pull "$@"
```

while `--autostash` when I need to pull manually from the terminal:

```
git pull --autostash
```